# Plesk error 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

I have a Windows 2008 Server, with MySQL and Plesk 12.0.18. It worked without problems till yesterday. Now, when trying to access the login page I get the following error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have tried connecting via Remote Desktop to the server and launch it from the server itself, but I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   An unknown FastCGI error occured Detailed Error Information
>   Module FastCgiModule 
>   Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
>   Handler PleskEngine-FastCGI-php 
>   Error Code 0x800700d8 
>   Requested URL https://localhost:8443/index.php 
>   Physical Path C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\htdocs\index.php 
>   Logon Method Anonymous 
>   Logon User Anonymous

I have made no modifications in Plesk since it was installed.

Some idea of what the problem could be?

These are the last entries in the php_error log:

[2015-09-23 14:03:45] Zend_Controller_Exception: Permission denied.#0 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\CommonPanel\Controller\Action\Abstract.php(191): CommonPanel_Controller_Action_Abstract->_checkForgeryProtectionToken()

## 1 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Action.php(502): CommonPanel_Controller_Action_Abstract->preDispatch()

## 2 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('errorAction')

## 3 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))

## 4 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\Application\Web.php(38): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(NULL)

## 5 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\htdocs\application.php(15): Plesk\Application_Web->run()

## 6 {main}

file: C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php
line: 336
code: 0
trace: #0 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Front.php(965): Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->postDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))

## 1 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\Application\Web.php(38): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(NULL)

## 2 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\htdocs\application.php(15): Plesk\Application_Web->run()

### #3 {main}

## 0 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\CommonPanel\Controller\Action\Abstract.php(191): CommonPanel_Controller_Action_Abstract->_checkForgeryProtectionToken()

## 1 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Action.php(502): CommonPanel_Controller_Action_Abstract->preDispatch()

## 2 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('errorAction')

## 3 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\externals\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))

## 4 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\Application\Web.php(38): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(NULL)

## 5 C:\Parallels\Plesk\admin\htdocs\application.php(15): Plesk\Application_Web->run()

## 6 {main}

[2015-09-25 03:20:46] ERR [panel] Task not responding: id=467, pid=131496, type=panel-update.

The first entry 2015-09-23 was pevious to the error in Plesk.

Comment: What is architecture of your server? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: The architecture is 64 bit, thanks

Comment: Is there any errors at C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\logs\php_error.log ?

Comment: I include the log in the question because it is too long

Comment: Yeah, actually nothing useful in log. Thinks it' really better to ask your hosting provider or Parallels/Odin support for assistance.